# EasyRTC - Change camera source

Tags: node.js, camera, webrtc, easyrtc

I'm developing a videochat using EasyRTC framework.

I have built up a small web application using Node.JS as server.

Everything is working fine and I can make video call.

When I'm using it from tablet or smartphone, default camera is front camera.

How can I switch to back camera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some search in source code, I’m able to set back camera in this way:

```
easyrtc.getVideoSourceList( function(list) {
       var i;
       for( i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
         alert("label=" + list[i].label + ", id= " + list[i].id);

         if(list[i].label.indexOf('back') > 0){  // Searching for label containing back (for back camera)
             easyrtc.setVideoSource(list[i].id);  // Set the id of back camera. Must be called before easyrtc.initMediaSource()
             easyrtc.initMediaSource(
                   function(){       // success callback
                       var selfVideo = document.getElementById("self");
                       easyrtc.setVideoObjectSrc(selfVideo, easyrtc.getLocalStream());
                       easyrtc.connect("Company_Chat_Line", connectSuccess, connectFailure);
                   },connectFailure
             );

             break;
         }
       }
```

For version v1.0.17 use `list[i].deviceid` instead of `list[i].id`

Comment: when i stringified the list index  there is property included named deviceid

Comment: In my project it's working. Do you solve it or still not working?

Comment: mmm if I'm not wrong the call easyrtc.getVideoSourceList(function(list){....}) is async. So maybe something like could be useful for you:

 [Link to async function](http://pastebin.com/9ij134Gk)

Comment: Hey if you are using v1.0.17, as stated in changelog of new release [New EasyRTC release](https://easyrtc.com/forum/) you should use "deviceid" instead of "id" for device id. So in my code should be `list[i].deviceid`. In my code I'm using an older versione of EasyRTC, so that's why it works

Comment: Hi, Is your app available in app store yet? I am integrating EasyRTC with ionic as well, and I would like to take a look at it.

Comment: It's a web app, not a Phonegapp/Apache Cordova. WebRTC must use HTTPS, dunno if you can use it Ionic.